# Why Map.putIfAbsent() is returning null?

Tags: java, hashmap

The following program is printing `null`. I am not able to understand why.

```
public class ConcurrentHashMapTest {
    public static final Map<String, String> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(5, 0.9f, 2);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        map.putIfAbsent("key 1", "value 1");
        map.putIfAbsent("key 2", "value 2");

        String value = get("key 3");
        System.out.println("value for key 3 --> " + value);
    }

    private static String get(final String key) {
        return map.putIfAbsent(key, "value 3");
    }
}
```

Could someone help me understand the behavior?

Comment: What behaviour did you *expect*, and why?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`ConcurrentMap.putIfAbsent` returns the previous value associated with the specified key, or null if there was no mapping for the key. You did not have a value associated with "key 3". All correct.

**NOTE:** Not just for `ConcurrentMap`, this applies to all implementations of `Map`.

Answer (score 44):

Problem is that by definition **putIfAbsent** return old value and not new value (old value for absent is always null). Use **computeIfAbsent** - this will return new value for you.

```
private static String get(final String key) {
    return map.computeIfAbsent(key, s -> "value 3");
}
```

Comment: it doesn't allow exception throwing, too bad.

Comment: As any other lambda. So either use @SneakyThrows or rethrow exception as RuntimeException.

Comment: `@SneakyThrows` is evil.

Comment: checked exceptions are far more evil than @SneakyThrows :)

Answer (score 7):

[`putIfAbsent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#putIfAbsent%28K,%20V%29) returns the previous value associated with the specified key, or `null` if there was no mapping for the key, and because `key 3` is not present in the map so it returns `null`.

You have added `key 1` and `key 2` in the map but `key 3` is not associated with any value. So you get a `null`. Map `key 3` with some value and `putIfAbsent()` will return previous value associated with that key.

Like if map already contained `key 3` associated with value `A`

```
key 3 ---> A
```

Then on calling `map.putIfAbsent("key 3","B")` will return `A`

Answer (score 6):

This is a frequently asked question, which perhaps suggest this behaviour is unintuitive. Maybe the confusion comes from the way dict.setdefault() works in python and other languages. Returning the same object you just put helps cut a few lines of code.

Consider:

```
if (map.contains(value)){
    obj = map.get(key);
}
else{
    obj = new Object();
}
```

versus:

```
obj = map.putIfAbsent(key, new Object());
```

Comment: Is this an atomic operation? As in, can the map change between contains and get?

Answer (score 4):

It's in the javadoc:

> returns the previous value associated with the specified key, or null if there was no mapping for the key

Comment: For quotes you should use `>`, not the code formatting.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot... :) haven't answered for a awhile

Answer (score 3):

Please read the documentation of [`ConcurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#putIfAbsent%28K,%20V%29):

> **Returns**:
>       the previous value associated with the specified key, or `null` if there was no mapping for the key

As there was no previous value for the key `"key 3"`, it returns `null`.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentation, it says

> Returns:
>  the previous value associated with the specified key, or
>   null if there was no mapping for the key

In your case, no value was previously associated with the key, hence `NULL`

Answer (score 0):

The current mapped value could be returned by using `merge` function. The following could would return the current non-null value if the key already exists, or returns the given new value if a mapping does not exist or if the value is `null`.

```java
private static String get(final String key) {
    return map.merge(key, "value 3", (oldVal, newVal) -> oldVal);
}
```

or in general:

```java
private T get(final String key, T value) {
    return map.merge(key, value, (oldVal, newVal) -> oldVal);
}
```

This could be useful when you do not prefer to use `computeIfAbsent` because the mapping function to `computeIfAbsent` could throw an exception, and you also do not want to do the below:

```java
map.putIfAbsent(key, value);
return map.get(key);
```

Answer (score 0):

All the answers are correct, and just to add a side note,

> If the specified key is not already associated with a value (or is
> mapped to null) associates it with the given value and returns null,
> else returns the current value.
>
> public V putIfAbsent(K key, V value) {
> return putVal(key, value, true); }

The key maintains in the table. The value can be retrieved by calling the get method with a key that is equal to the original key before put. If the key is not found in the table then returns null.